# positional argument follows keyword argument issue in Django ORM query

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
user=kwargs['user']

Emp.objects.filter(country="England",Q(euser=user)|Q(muser=user),dep="sample").order-by('-date')
```

Throwing the error

```
 positional argument follows keyword argument issue in Q(euser=user)|Q(muser=user)
```

Comment: Put the `Q(...)` before the `country=...` arg…?!

Answer (score 1):

According to Python syntax, positional arguments must be passed before keyword arguments. `country=...` is a keyword argument, `Q(...)` is not. This is even mentioned explicitly in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> Lookup functions can mix the use of `Q` objects and keyword arguments. All arguments provided to a lookup function (be they keyword arguments or `Q` objects) are “AND”ed together. However, if a `Q` object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments.